# Why do 15.04 gnome-shell topbar icons stop working

Tags: 15.04, gnome-panel

Ubuntu 15.04 using Tweak-tool, autohide, topicons, workspaces dock extensions are all activated.

The problem occurs after topbar autohide.  Dropbox and Libreoffice drop down menu both disappear.

The only way I have found that will return them to the topbar is to save all my work, then logout and login.

Does anyone have a solution to avoid this annoying (save files, then logout and login) procedure?

Comment: Does restarting gnome shell help (alt-f2, `r`)? Also check if the extensions have any updates.

Comment: Yes, it corrects the problem, but what causes the problem?

Comment: Not sure how to check for extension updates, I use `sudo apt-get update` often.  Will that include the Tweak-tool extensions?

Comment: Open http://extensions.gnome.org in Firefox, and look at the "installed extensions" section.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  There was one update.  It made no difference in topbar behavior.  What was most helpful was the restart, it keeps me from having to save my open files.  Can you convert you comment to an answer, so I can give you credit for the assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete re-login can perhaps be avoided by restarting GNOME Shell. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, and run the `r` command. (Another useful command could be `lg`, for the Looking Glass, where you can inspect the state of GNOME Shell and its extensions.)